# Python: ¿Cómo eliminar cualquier carácter duplicado de un String excepto un carácter en especifico?

Tags: python, string, caracteres

El objetivo es eliminar cualquier carácter que sea repetido de un String, pero con la restricción de que el único carácter que puede estar repetido es la coma ","

Es decir, si tengo el siguiente String en Python:

```
universo = "a,f,h,4,a,h,g"
```

Debería quedar:

```
universo = "a,f,h,4,g"
```

Use la el siguiente código para eliminar los elementos repetidos, pero el problema está en que elimina la coma incluida:

```
universo = "".join(dict.fromkeys(universo))
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Es importante el orden de los caracteres en la salida?

Comment: Como usas dict.fromkeys() doy por supuesto o que no te importa el orden, o que te importa y estas en una versión python3.7 o superior. Entonces si quiere conseguirlo en una línea podrías usar: universo = ",".join(c for c in dict.fromkeys(universo) if c!=',')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solución sin preservar el orden**

La función `split(car)` permite dividir una cadena separada por el caracter indicado. En este caso, nos interesa dividir por la coma, por lo que usamos `split(",")`.

La función `set` construye un conjunto (*set*) a partir de la lista de entrada, eliminando los duplicados.

Con `",".join()` creamos una cadena poniendo "," entre cada elemento.

Eso es

```
universo = "a,f,h,4,a,h,g"
sin_comas = universo.split(",")
nuevo = ','.join(set(sin_comas))
print(nuevo)
```

produce:

```
g,a,h,4,f
```

**Solución preservando el orden**

Después de dividir la cadena usando `split`, la recorremos formando la lista `sin_coma`, descartando los repetidos:

```
universo = "a,f,h,4,a,h,g"
sin_comas = []
for elemento in universo.split(","):
    if elemento not in sin_comas:
        sin_comas.append(elemento)
nuevo = ','.join(sin_comas)
print(nuevo)
```

produce:

```
a,f,h,4,g
```

Answer (score 3):

Para una versión que preserve el orden y que escale bien para listas de gran tamaño (que se ejecute en un tiempo O(n) en vez de O(n^2)), podemos aprovecharnos de que a partir de la versión 3.7 de Python  los diccionarios garantizan el orden de inserción.

Es decir, al recorrer un diccionario las claves te van saliendo en el mismo orden en que fueron insertadas. Por otro lado, si una clave ya existía en un diccionario, no se volverá a insertar, por lo que es un buen mecanismo para eliminar duplicados.

Usando esta idea puedes reducir el código a una línea:

```
nuevo = ",".join({c:1 for c in universo.split(",")})
```

El resultado en `nuevo` es `"a,f,h,4,g"`

### Cómo funciona

A `",".join()` le estoy pasando un diccionario que se está creando allí mismo por compresión. Ese diccionario usa como claves `c` cada una de las letras que restultan de dividir `universo` por las comas, y como valor 1 (aunque el valor es irrelevante).

La primera vez que aparezca una letra, se insertará en el diccionario con valor 1. La segunda vez que aparezca se sobreescribirá el 1 de la primera vez (aunque de nuevo con el valor 1). Los valores son irrelevantes, pues lo que nos interesan son las claves (letras de `universo`) y el orden en que fueron insertadas por primera vez.

`",".join()` iterará por las claves de ese diccionario, juntando todas en una sola cadena separadas por comas, logrando la salida deseada.